# Compare two nonparametric curve estimation approaches: kernel and orthogonal basis

Tags: estimation, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing

I know there're at least two approaches for nonparametric curve estimation: kernel and orthogonal basis.

What are their advantages and disadvantages over each other?

And what are the typical application scenarios of each approach?

Could anyone give a hopefully not-too-long explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Both (as well as other scatter-plot smothers such as splines and their generalizations) can be viewed as minimizing the fitting error (subject to a smoothing constraint) of projections of the data unto different norms.

You will find a precise explanation of the differences between the two on pages 11-15 of

- *A General Projection Framework for Constrained Smoothing*
  E. Mammen, J. S. Marron, B. A. Turlach and M. P. Wand.

avalaible ungated [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-16/issue-3/A-General-Projection-Framework-for-Constrained-Smoothing/10.1214/ss/1009213727.full)